# Посоветуйте легкий сервер

Tags: apache, веб-сервер

Посоветуйте самый легкий web-сервер для Windows чисто для отображения одной html-страницы.

Comment: Tomcat и аналоги недостаточно легкие?

Comment: А нет чего-нибудь полегче, чтобы просто запустить, и один-единственный html-файл был доступен по выделенному IP?

Comment: nginx? (еще 9 символов нужно)

Answer (score 0):

Этот скрипт   просто запустит подобие веб-сервера ,на вашем localhost и порту 8080.

```
import http.server
import socketserver

PORT = 8080
Handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

with socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler) as httpd:
  print("serving at port", PORT)
  httpd.serve_forever()
```